Must I logout the user after updating their email address?
I have been working on simple profile editing functionalities for my application.  A user's journey to update their profile info may look like the following.
Navigate to ProfileView(), click on a button which will switch from a view of their current info to an 'edit view' with TextFormFields, etc.  When finished with the changes, user taps the save button which I suppose is pretty self-explanatory.
In the context of changing their email, upon pressing save button a dialog pops up for the user to enter their password and reauthenticate. Then the backend functionality is triggered which sends the email change verification.  Once this email is responded to by the user, the email is successfully changed in FirebaseAuth.
My problem was trying to get the 'view-only' email text in ProfileView() to update.  This data is read with 'user!.email!' with 'user' representing the currently logged in firebase user.  As much as I toyed around with trying to get the state to update, it did not want to do so.  Hot restarting did not solve anything and even printing user.email would not display the new email that I could see had been changed in the Firebase console.
After too much digging I came across the userChanges() stream provided by FirebaseAuth.  I implemented this in didChangeDependencies() hoping to rebuild the email text by reloading the user object:
@override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();

    FirebaseAuth.instance.userChanges().listen((User? user) async {
      await user!.reload();
    });
  }

This threw an error:

[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_auth/user-token-expired] The user's credential is no longer valid. The user must sign in again.

This made things a bit more clear; it explains why the only way I could get the email text to update was signing the user out and signing in with the new email.  But here I am now, wondering if the user really must go through an entire sign in process again, immediately after having to reenter their password to reauthenticate and change email in the first place.
P.S. -- I'm not entirely sure if I called userChanges() in a correct manner or if it should be in didChangeDependencies at all, I'm still relatively new at this.
